# Community wiki card - text looks wrong

Tags: bug, design, community-wiki

Sometimes a community wiki post has a percentage attached to it. It means that a certain percentage of the post was written by a specific user, as described in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299780/509868).

The problem is, the resulting text looks confusing. For example (this example was taken from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/509868)):

```
community wiki
193 revs, 13 users 36%
JasonMArcher
```

It seems that there is always a linebreak between the percentage and the user's name, which makes it unclear what the percentage really means.

The following designs look better:

```
community wiki
193 revs, 13 users
36% JasonMArcher
```

```
community wiki
193 revs, 13 users
36% by JasonMArcher
```

They may be implemented by adding a non-breaking space, as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299776/what-do-the-statistics-for-a-community-wiki-represent/299780#comment224648_299780), or a forced linebreak before the percentage.